# Reading from socket input stream

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to determine the best way to transfer data through a socket between a client and server. Currently I have a BufferedReader that reads one character at a time (or however many characters have arrived since the last iteration). Through each iteration, it pulls the data received so far and puts it into an array. When the '|' character is read, it knows that the current instruction is done.

I know what I have so far is grossly inefficient and burns the CPU, but I'm a little unclear as to the differences between all the ways to read from a socket input stream. What would I use to not have to read each character at a time, but rather to wait until the input stream is finished receiving the current instruction (which would be terminated by "\n")?

Comment: If your commands are \n-terminated, why read char by char at all instead of calling BufferedReader.readLine()?

Comment: As I understand it, and perhaps I may be wrong, doesn't readline read what's currently in the buffer? So Let's say I'm sending the word "hello", and only "he" has arrived, doesn't it only read that?

Comment: Readline blocks until the full line is read. You get partial data only for the char array based read() methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the best way is to create a new thread for each socket/client that listens for input. `readLine()` always works for me fine. Perhaps [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) might help you out a bit.